# Extracting from VirtualBox or VMWare vHDD

Tags: virtualbox, clone, system-restore

I have VirtualBox installed in my system. I installed Windows XP Pro SP3 in VB guest. Then I installed all the applications I need, i.e. MS Office, Winamp etc.

Now, if the OS I use crashes, can I extract the contents of VB virtual HDD to my physical HDD, so that I can carry on my work without the hassle of reinstalling all the software?

Answer (score 1):

In general you can't move applications from one Windows system (e.g. one in a VM) to another Windows system simply by copying files. You have to reinstall.

See http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_copy_preinstalled_software_to_another_machine.html

Answer (score 0):

No, as RedGrittyBrick says, copying Windows installations doesn't let you use them in general.

What you *can* do is make a backup copy of the virtual machine itself on removable or external media. This way, if your system crashes you can install any OS you want *on any PC you want*, reinstall VirtualBox (free of charge) and keep using the VM. Of course, this requires you to do all your work using the VM rather than the host OS.

Note: the above requires you to keep your data outside the VM, or back it up regularly. Regular backups are a good idea in any case, of course.